# How to remove (most) short words from a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently using the following regex to remove small words ( < 4 chars) from a string.

```
$dirty = "I welcome you to San Diego";
$clean = preg_replace("/\b[^\s]{1,3}\b/", "", $dirty);
```

So, this would result in "Welcome Diego";

However, i now need to ignore certain words from being replaced, for instance:

```
$ignore = array("San", "you");
```

would result in **"welcome you San Diego"**

Comment: Most search engines deal with this by specifying a blacklist of "stopwords". http://armandbrahaj.blog.al/2009/04/14/list-of-english-stop-words/

Comment: What is `[^\s]` used for instead of `\S`? Also, do you realize that `\b` is not defined in terms of `\S`-vs-`\s`, but rather, in terms of `\w` alone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using a callback ([preg_replace_callback](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)) as it allows a more maintainable solution if you have to scale to a large number of words:

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/\b[^\s]{1,3}\b/',
    create_function(
        '$matches',
        '$ignore = array("San", "you");
         if (in_array($matches[0], $ignore)) {
            return $matches[0];
         } else {
            return \'\';
         }'
    ),
    "I welcome you to San Diego"
); 
// output: welcome you San Diego
```

If you're using PHP 5.3 or greater, you could employ an anonymous function rather than calling [create_function](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php).

Comment: Do keep in mind that create_function produces a known memory leak. Best to avoid it.

Comment: I think you want `\b\w{1,3}\b` there.

Answer (score 9):

You can embed your ignore list using a `(?!..)` [negative assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
 preg_replace("/\b(?!San|you|not)\w{1,3}\b/", "", ...
```

Also I would just use `\w` instead of `[^\s]` so it really only matches words.

Comment: This seems like a much more elegant approach than the callback, and it likely performs better too.

Comment: @Frits: It's also easier to embed a `|`-imploded word list here. But nevertheless I also upvoted the callback alternative ;} even if only because I think preg_replace_callback is mentioned too seldomly.

Comment: @Frits: Indeed, the only "drawback" is that you should run the word list through `preg_quote` before imploding by `|`, but this can also be done in one line with `array_map` so it's not a big deal. Dunno why this answer wasn't accepted instead.